# Cannot open local terminal on Android Studio (on Mac)

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal

I cannot open the terminal on Android Studio and the error says:

```
Cannot open Local Terminal Failed to start [/bin/bash, --rcfile, /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in, -i] in /Users/{UserName}/Android
See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in Finder) for the details.
```

If you have any idea, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Solution for M1 Mac (Apple silicon)
First of all you need to Open the Android Studio Preview app and close completely from you docks. and run the following commands.

```
git clone https://github.com/JetBrains/pty4j.git
cd pty4j/native
clang -fPIC -c *.c
clang -shared -o libpty.dylib *.o
cp libpty.dylib "/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/lib/pty4j-native/darwin/"
```

Comment: Thank you very much I had this problem for some time and I couldn't solve it.
Everything is OK now.
Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Press Command + Comma to open android studio preference:
[image]

Click the folder icon and select your favorite terminal:
[image]

Comment: I changed it to zsh, still shows the error. 

`Cannot open Local Terminal
Failed to start [/bin/zsh, --login, -i] in /Users/{UserName}/Android`

Comment: I just got it when I updated OS to latest version. Thanks so much :) @navylover

Comment: Any solution for this problem?